# Unwanted segue occuring while using a UITableView

Tags: uitableview, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a `UItableView` and I perform a segue to a `UIView`. The information varies on the presented `UIView` depending on what row is selected in the `UITableView`. The `UIView` gets presented perfectly. 
The problem is that when the new `UIView` is presented, if I click in the same place on the screen where the initial row was, I then segue back to the `UITableView`.

I made a segue on the storyboard called `dayx`.
I then used the following code to present the new `UIView`.
Here is the code I used to perform the segue:

```
  //when row is pressed what happens
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let destinationVC = segue.destination as! foodinfo
    destinationVC.counter = rowselected
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    rowselected = indexPath.row
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "dayx", sender: self)

    //making desleected row not highlighted
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

the presented `UIView` code is as follows:

class foodinfo: UIViewController {

```
var counter = Int()
let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()

@IBOutlet var tabs: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet var theTitleLable: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var stack: UIStackView!
@IBOutlet var ScrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet var foodImageview: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var navBar: UINavigationBar!


var simpleViewX: UIView!
var simpleViewY: UIView!

var theTitleArray = ["title1","title2","title3","title4","title5","title6","title7"]
var theImageArray = ["image1", "image2", "image3","image4","image5",image6","image7"]


//video links
var calledVideo: String?

let vids = ["https://vimeo.com/123456789","https://vimeo.com/123456789", "https://vimeo.com/123456789", "https://vimeo.com/123456789","https://vimeo.com/123456789","https://vimeo.com/123456789","https://vimeo.com/123456789"]


override func viewDidLoad() {

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.deviceOrientationDidChange), name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    getTitle()
    getImage()
    getNavbar()

    //Different subViews for ingredients and steps
    if counter == 0 {

        simpleViewX = SimpleVC0().view
        simpleViewY = SimpleVC1().view

        stack.addArrangedSubview(simpleViewX)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(simpleViewY)

        simpleViewY.isHidden = true

    }

    if counter == 1 {
        simpleViewX = SimpleVC2().view
        simpleViewY = SimpleVC3().view

        stack.addArrangedSubview(simpleViewX)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(simpleViewY)

        simpleViewY.isHidden = true

    }

    if counter == 2 {
        simpleViewX = SimpleVC4().view
        simpleViewY = SimpleVC5().view

        stack.addArrangedSubview(simpleViewX)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(simpleViewY)

        simpleViewY.isHidden = true
    }

    if counter == 3 {
        simpleViewX = SimpleVC6().view
        simpleViewY = SimpleVC7().view

        stack.addArrangedSubview(simpleViewX)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(simpleViewY)

        simpleViewY.isHidden = true
    }

    if counter == 4 {
        simpleViewX = SimpleVC8().view
        simpleViewY = SimpleVC9().view

        stack.addArrangedSubview(simpleViewX)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(simpleViewY)

        simpleViewY.isHidden = true
    }

    if counter == 5 {
        simpleViewX = SimpleVC10().view
        simpleViewY = SimpleVC11().view

        stack.addArrangedSubview(simpleViewX)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(simpleViewY)

        simpleViewY.isHidden = true
    }

    if counter == 6 {
        simpleViewX = SimpleVC12().view
        simpleViewY = SimpleVC13().view

        stack.addArrangedSubview(simpleViewX)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(simpleViewY)

        simpleViewY.isHidden = true
    }

}


func getTitle() {
    theTitleLable.text = theTitleArray[counter]
}

func getImage() {
    foodImageview.image = UIImage(named: theImageArray[counter] + ".jpg")
}

func getNavbar () {
    self.navBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.navBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
}



@IBAction func tabselected(_ sender: Any) {
    switch (sender as AnyObject).selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        //shiftView.bringSubviewToFront(simpleViewX)
        simpleViewY.isHidden = true
        simpleViewX.isHidden = false

        break
    case 1:
        //shiftView.bringSubviewToFront(simpleViewY)

        simpleViewX.isHidden = true
        simpleViewY.isHidden = false

        break
    case 2:
        //calledvideo in array is the value of the counter.
        calledVideo = vids[counter]
        geturl()


        break
    default:
        break
    }
}

//Getting url info for video by using exractor
func geturl() {
    if let url = URL(string: calledVideo!) {
        HCVimeoVideoExtractor.fetchVideoURLFrom(url: url, completion: { ( video:HCVimeoVideo?, error:Error?) -> Void in

            if let err = error {
                DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: err.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                return
            }

            guard let vid = video else {
                print("Invalid video object")
                return
            }


            //play video
            let player = AVPlayer(url: vid.videoURL[.Quality540p]!)
            self.playerController.player = player
            self.present(self.playerController, animated: true) {
                player.play()
            }
        })

    }
}

//ROTATION OF VIDEO BUT NOT ALLOWING VC TO ROTATE---this is the guy you got-----
@objc func deviceOrientationDidChange() {
    switch UIDevice.current.orientation {
    case .faceUp, .faceDown, .portrait, .unknown, .portraitUpsideDown:
        // default the player to original rotation
        self.playerController.view.transform = .identity
        self.playerController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height)

    /*case .landscapeLeft:

       print("Landscape left")
       self.playerController.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat((90 * Double.pi)/180))
        self.playerController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height)*/

    case .landscapeRight, .landscapeLeft:

                  print("Landscape right")
                  self.playerController.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat((-90 * Double.pi)/180))
        self.playerController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height)
    }
}
//---------------------------------------
```

}

I have no idea why it segues back to the `UITableView`. Anyone know what im doing wrong?

Comment: Please share the UIView code that is presented when row is selected in UItableView.

Comment: @Anand have added the code.

Comment: i have figured out that it only happens when i set `dayx` to present modally. i wish to use the curl effect but none of the other options have this effect.

Comment: please note, it is not presenting `UIView` , but `UIViewController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that you're using a Storyboard and that you've connected your two views `UITableView` and destination `UIView` with a segue with `identifier` "dayx".

Is there some specific reason you're overriding `tableView(didSelectRowAt:)`?

Have you considered or attempted to use code similar to this (and removing `tableView(didSelectRowAt:)`)...?

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier = "dayx" {

        if let rowSelected = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {

            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! foodinfo
            destinationVC.counter = rowSelected
        }
    }
}
```

Also set the following default property (in `viewWillAppear(animated)`)to suit your UI...
`clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = true` (or false).